# Removing duplicate data when renaming keys after join

Tags: python, rethinkdb

My code is:

```
dbobj = dbobj.merge(  lambda row: {'right': row['right'].coerce_to('array').map(
                      lambda pair: [r.expr(field[:-2]) + pair[0], pair[1]]
                    ).coerce_to('object')}).zip()
```

I tried doing {'new': instead of {'right': but zip doesn't let me choose to do new instead of right.

How do I remove the original key names on the right side? I know I need to use without but not sure how to loop through just the original names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your new value for `right` to replace your old value, you can use `r.literal` for that: `.merge(lambda row: {'right': r.literal(...)})`.